# Dispatch event on the angular element in jasmine test is not working

Tags: angularjs-directive, jasmine, google-closure

In my test case I am trying something like this:

```
element = angular.element('<div></div>')
element.trigger('mouseenter');
```

But, there is error saying "undefined is not a function". I think its because I am not using jquery. I also, tried this:

```
goog.events.dispatchEvent(element[0], 'mouseenter');
```

But, it says that "Assertion failed: Can not use goog.events.dispatchEvent with non-goog.events.Listenable instance"

Is there any work around?

Comment: I guess, you haven't included js libraries correctly. Check the order.

Comment: I can't/don't want to include Jquery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're after is triggering mouse events programatically. No workarounds or  libraries are needed for this. The objects or methods to be used depend on the environments that you want to target.

Triggering events programatically involves creating custom events. Since you control this custom event, you also decide whether it's cancelable or bubbles. Note that [`mouseenter` on IE does not bubble](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html#mouseenter).

The element event target below is not wrapped by any DOM library - it's just a reference to a DOM element named `targetEl`.

**Current spec**: Use the [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) constructor.

```
var event = new MouseEvent('mouseenter', { 
  'view': window, 
  'bubbles': true, 
  'cancelable': true 
});
targetEl.dispatchEvent(event);
```

**Older spec**: Use [`document.createEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent) and [`event.initEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.initEvent).

```
var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
event.initEvent('mouseenter', true /*bubbles*/, true /*cancelable*/);
targetEl.dispatchEvent(event);
```

**IE 8 and below**: Use [`document.createEventObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`fireEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
var event = document.createEventObject();
targetEl.fireEvent('onmouseenter', event);
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZTfC/2)</kbd>

---

For the part of your question that involved Closure: `goog.events.dispatchEvent` will not take a raw DOM element as event target, as it expects an object implementing a specific interface (a [Listenable](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/interface_goog_events_Listenable.html)). As for Angular, its *jqLite* implementation doesn't include jQuery's `.trigger()` method.

The above approach is the way to go unless you are specifically evaluating the ability of libraries to trigger custom events (in contrast to responding to them) in your test environment.

Comment: Sry, but the above code is not working from console.

Comment: Did you get a reference to the element first? Something like: `targetEl = document.getElementById('the-element')`. Alternatively, can you provide the error message? All the snippets I posted are in use on the linked JSFiddle, too.

Answer (score -1):

In case your dom is not rendered before this code execution.

use setTimeout in dispatchEvent Like :

```js
setTimeout(()=>{
  $('.any_class')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event("keyup"));
},3000);
```